# Code snippet to parse mysql output from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'll write it, but if there's a ready, tested code snippet that does this I'll be happy to steal it.

```
COUNT(*)    SUM(cnt)
0   1
```

**Edit** - Thanks for the votes to close, I can always count on the good souls in Stack Overflow to be quick with the close votes. I'll add some details to the question.

I am looking for a java code snippet that can parse the output of running "mysql" executable. The snippet above is an example of such an output that I would like to parse.

Comment: WTF? Can you please change your answer?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if there's one.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, @Chouchenos - edited the question.

Comment: check out a ORM tool like iBatis, myBatis, or Hibernate.  These mask the details of JDBC nicely.

Comment: @dwb - I'm not sure why everyone is missing the point here. I don't want to run the queries, I only want to parse the result of the queries. Text files.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
and modify it for your format (that is Comma Seperated, your's looks to be white-space seperated)

Answer (score 2):

This is close to trivial to parse using [`java.util.Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc). You can find the [MySql JDBC driver here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html).

Comment: What I specifically wanted here was not to run the queries via JDBC, but rather parse queries that are run by the stand alone mysql client. I have my reasons (not very interesting ones), but I admit they're not particularly strong. I might switch to JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a specific snippet for my needs. I only need to support specific queries, so I didn't write a generic parser for mysql output. Here is my code, anyway:

```
  String[] lines = sqlOutput.toLowerCase().split("\n");
  if (lines.length != 2) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to parse, bad header line");
  }

  String headers = lines[0];
  String body = lines[1];

  if (!headers.startsWith("count(*)"))
    throw new Exception("Query output must start with 'count(*)'")

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(body);
  return scanner.nextInt()
```